# How can I make this email signature responsive/mobile friendly?

Tags: html, email, gmail, responsive

I have an email signature which consists of a simple table (one row, two columns). The first column has a logo, the second column has all the contact details.

I would like to make it responsive so that on small devices the logo is shown above, and the contact details below (so effectively the columns turn into rows). Currently, on small devices, the table gets squeezed so that the contact details are not readable.

```
<div style="color: #222222; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12.8px;">
  <div class="m_159975109461180827gmail_signature">
    <div dir="ltr">
      <div dir="ltr">
        <table style="color: #000000; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: medium; background: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px initial initial;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right-width: 3px; border-right-color: #d2ac67; padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px; vertical-align: middle;" valign="top"><img class="CToWUd" src="http://mywebsite.com/logo-small.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;">
                <table style="background: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 93px; border: 0px initial initial;" border="0" width="300" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px; color: #d2ac67; font-size: 14px;" colspan="2"><strong>My Name</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; color: #333333; font-size: 12px;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #d2ac67;">My position&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;Name of the company</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: #d2ac67; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="20">p:</td>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; color: #333333; font-size: 12px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #1155cc;" href="tel:+44%2020%207099%206646" target="_blank">+44 1234566</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #d2ac67;">m:&nbsp;</span><a style="color: #1155cc;" href="tel:+44%207491%20044801" target="_blank">+44&nbsp;1</a>234567</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: #d2ac67; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="20">a:</td>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; color: #333333; font-size: 12px;" valign="top">some addresss</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: #d2ac67; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="20">w:</td>
                      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top; color: #333333; font-size: 12px;" valign="top">link to the website</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all in advance for your help/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a table create another table with your rows as columns and assign each table a class.  Use css to hide and show the different tables using media calls.

Comment: Is this the only/smoothest way to do it? I would prefer to avoid doubling the code, especially for an email signature. 

Maybe if I put the logo outside of the table (but to the left of the table with contact data) and then add fixed width for the table, the table will "unstick" and be moved below on narrow screens?

Comment: you could place the image and table in separate div tags and then use media queries to change their placement depending on screen size